# Merging two different sonar reports from same project

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, teamcity, sonarscanner

I have a legacy project, which is having 40M+ lines of code. I just want to configure the sonar during build but when I run sonar with default settings, it fails with OutOfMemoryException or with TimeOutException.

I got to know that this is because of the large codebase that I am having, so I increased the memory arguments to use 5 GB of memory. I tried with more memory but the teamcity server doesn't have much free memory. Still failed.

Finally what I did was, built two pipelines, included a particular file pattern in one using `sonar.inclusions` rest of the files in other and separated my code into two different pipelines. Now when I run the sonar, it works fine and generates two different reports with different project keys.

But my requirement is to generate a single report because I can't attach two reports in bitbucket. My goal is to show the report in bitbucket. If it is possible to fetch two reports in single repository, that will also do the thing.

Can anyone please help me here to generate a single report even though I run sonar in multiple pipelines in teamcity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. A project (you call it 'report') is the only unit you can scan in one execution of the sonar scanner - you can't scan part of a project.
If you're using Enterprise edition, you can create a portfolio of multiple projects, which will automatically generate and maintain aggregated metrics.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: I don't think so.